Why does the congratulations message not display in a div using document.getElementById
I've written the below code and need to change the window.alert messages so that they show in a div box instead. However, I've started with the initial congratulations message and it doesn't appear at all. Below is my code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> Hide And Seek </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
var diamond;
var number_of_guesses;

diamond = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);

number_of_guesses = 0;

function check(guess) {
    if(diamond == guess)
    {
        // window.alert("Congratulations! You have found the diamond.");
        document.getElementById('messageBox').textContent = 'Congratulations! You have found the diamond!';
        
        again = window.prompt("Would you like to play another game? Enter Y or N.", "Y");
        
        if(again == "N" || again == "n")
        {
            window.alert("Thanks for playing. Goodbye.");
            window.close();
        }
        else
        {
            window.alert("The diamond has been hidden. You can now try again.");
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        number_of_guesses = number_of_guesses + 1;
        
        if(diamond < guess)
        {
            result = "lower"
        }
        else
        {
            result = "higher"
        }
        window.alert("Guess number " + number_of_guesses + " is incorrect. Diamond is " + result + ".");
    }
    if(number_of_guesses >= 3)
    {
        window.alert("Sorry, you have run out of guesses! The diamond was in box " + diamond);
        
        again = window.prompt("Would you like to play another game? Enter Y or N.", "Y");
        
        if(again == "N" || again == "n")
        {
            window.alert("Thanks for playing. Goodbye.");
            window.close();
        }
        else
        {
            window.alert("The diamond has been hidden. You can now try again.");
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="hidenseek">
    <input id="box1" type="button" value="1" onClick="check(box1.value)">
    <input id="box2" type="button" value="2" onClick="check(box2.value)">
    <input id="box3" type="button" value="3" onClick="check(box3.value)">
    <input id="box4" type="button" value="4" onClick="check(box4.value)">
    <input id="box5" type="button" value="5" onClick="check(box5.value)"> <br>
    <input id="box6" type="button" value="6" onClick="check(box6.value)">
    <input id="box7" type="button" value="7" onClick="check(box7.value)">
    <input id="box8" type="button" value="8" onClick="check(box8.value)">
    <input id="box9" type="button" value="9" onClick="check(box9.value)">
    <input id="box10" type="button" value="10" onClick="check(box10.value)"> <p>
</form>

<h3 id="messageBox"> Click on the box of your choice. </h3>

</body>
</html>

I've changed all other window.alert messages to the same and they work fine, apart from the congratulations message

The text is showing, but things like prompt and alert are blocking operations which prevent the page from being updated until after the user dismissed them, and immediately after dismissing them you either close the page or reload the page which resets everything.  If your goal is to move away from things like prompt and alert and instead update the page UI (which is certainly recommended) then it sounds like you just need to finish doing that, and also remove the parts where you reload the page.

Try doing this, make a function that receives the message as a parameter, and defines it in document.getElementById. Like this:
 function displayMessage(message) {     document.getElementById('messageBox').textContent = message; }

Just delay your congratulations alert by 10 ms and it should work just fine:
if (diamond == guess) {
      // window.alert("Congratulations! You have found the diamond.");
      document.getElementById("messageBox").innerHTML =
        "Congratulations! You have found the diamond!";

      setTimeout(() => {
        again = window.prompt(
          "Would you like to play another game? Enter Y or N.",
          "Y"
        );

        if (again == "N" || again == "n") {
          window.alert("Thanks for playing. Goodbye.");
          window.close();
        } else {
          window.alert(
            "The diamond has been hidden. You can now try again."
          );
          window.location.reload();
        }
      }, 100);
    }

